# How to change the text inside a list item on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a list that has Home, Shop, Forums, and Apps/Applications.  On that list I want to have Apps to be shown but when you hover over the list item for it to change to the word Applications.  I want it to change anywhere inside the list item and not only on the text hover.  So I want to be able to hover anywhere in the list area and not just on the word for it to change.  If anyone knows how to do this then that would be awesome.  I just need the code and for you to tell me where I would put this in my code and what I need to change the names to.  Thank you.

This is the html I have for the list item

```
<a href="#">
<li class="item drop"><a href="#">Apps</a>
```

Comment: `I need code, you tell me where to put it`....that's just not how things work around here. You should be providing code that shows both html structure and what you have tried

Comment: We want to help, but we can't. There simply isn't enough information for us to do so. It would be like me asking you to help paint my house, but then I refuse to tell you where my house is.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you want something like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Shop</li>
    <li>Forum</li>
    <li class="container"><span class="full">Applications</span><span class="small">Apps</span></li>
</ul>
```

Applications and Apps in same position, changing on hover state of the list.

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}
.full, .small{
    position:absolute;    
}
.full{
    opacity:0;
}
.list:hover .full{
    opacity:1;
}
.list:hover .small{
    opacity:0;
}
```

no javascript ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/sagix/wJsGn/

Comment: I edited the post with the html I am using, I didn't know how to wrap that around what I had.

Comment: to add something like that: `<li class="container"><a href="#"><span class="full">Applications</span><span class="small">Apps</span></a></li>`